# TransientObjectException in grails

Tags: grails

I am working on a project and I have two domains.

```
class Author {
     Book book
     String name
}

class Book {
     Author author
     String title
}
```

I have saved an instance of domain Author in database and in a service I do something like this:

```
def authorInstance = Author.getById(1)
def bookInstance = new Book(author:authorInstance, title: "Foo")
```

But i do not save the bookInstance rather, I use it for couple of more processes. This gives me org.hibernate.TransientObjectException. I also tried to do something like:

```
def authorInstance = Author.getById(1)
def aI = authorInstance
def bookInstance = new Book(aI, title: "Foo")
```

But in this case too, I get the same error. I am working in this way because I am working in legacy code, so I cannot change much. Is there a work around for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You're apparently changeing some field of authorInstance you set. That's what `TransientObjectException` says: `"object references an unsaved transient instance"`. Please do read and do quote the error messages.

Save the `Author` before saving a book. Or do not modify it.

An you probably would like to use [hasMany](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasMany.html) and [belongsTo](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html).

Answer (score 0):

By the way, there is another issue with your possible replacement code.  Instead of:

```
def bookInstance = new Book(aI, title: "Foo")
```

you would need

```
def bookInstance = new Book(author:aI, title: "Foo")
```

Book has an in-memory constructor declared which takes a Map object and "author" and "title" are keys into that Map.  This constructure then uses the map to initialize class members.